# How to handle email invite system with user accounts

Tags: php, user-input

What's the standard/best way to handle the following situation?

A user enters email address user1@example.com to send an invite to an event on a website. The person receiving the invite already has an account at the website but has signed up with user2@example.com as their email address.

How do I verify that it's the right person while letting the user sign in with their actual account? I can use an invite ID to tie that account with that invite but what's stopping any person with access to that ID logging in?

Comment: If an account already exists for the email address, then you cant stop whoever uses the mail (and so can read the invite) or anyone who knows the password.. in an ideal world where everyone had a fixed IP you might but, too many places havent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your level of trust.  You have a few choices:

- Trust the person sending the invite.  Anyone who visits with a valid invite response URL can register with their choice of email, regardless of who was sent the invite.
- Deny invite responses where the recipient and registered user email addresses don't match.
- Only let users send invites for people already registered and have them choose the right account within the system.

Comment: These are the three choices I came down to and was hoping there was another way around it that I was missing. I think I'm going to have the system ask for a name and if they can't find the person they're after then ask them for an email address. From their I guess choice 1 is my only real option. Thanks for the help